# Trying to schedule Python job in SSMS

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to schedule a job in SQL Server MGMT Studio (2017).  As an example, when I run the below script,

---

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'Python',   
    @script = N'
        print("Hello World")'
```

---

I get an error that states, "Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_execute_external_script'."

Then when I try to enable this with

---

```
EXEC sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

---

I get this error:

"Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62 [Batch Start Line 10]
The configuration option 'external scripts enabled' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option."

Comment: What is `SELECT @@VERSION`? The version of management studio isn't relevant.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU6) (KB4019094) - 12.0.5553.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2017 16:26:18   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: SQL Server (starting with 2016), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/external-scripts-enabled-server-configuration-option

Comment: 2017 for Python AFAIK. 2016 was R

Answer (score 0):

@R Richards, 
If you aren't finding sys.sp_execute_external_script, it sounds like you haven't quite set up the db environment yet. After you enabled the feature using sp_configure, did you restart the instance? For more set up info see [Setup Machine Learning Services with Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/setup-python-machine-learning-services). Once that's square, don't forget to import sys and os.

Try something that looks closer to this:

```
DECLARE @ParamINT INT = 1234567
DECLARE @ParamCharN VARCHAR(6) = 'INPUT '
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import sys
import os
print("*******************************")
print(sys.version)
print("Hello World")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Seems that my server version is only 2014 so sys.sp_execute_external_script won't work.

Comment: Sorry @Mitchatwork -- well, download a copy of mssql 2017 and give it another try! :)